# jhipster compilation very slow (mvnw -Pprod takes more than an hour)

Tags: angular, performance, webpack, jhipster, webpack-production

When I want to compile my jhipster with 47 created entities, it takes a lot of time (between 55 min and 1h15).

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------- -------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 58:38 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-09T18: 47: 16 + 01: 00
```

The command used is: **`mvnw clean install package -DskipTests -Pprod`**

What takes time seems to be the webpack:

```
[INFO] > npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile  
[INFO]  
[INFO]  
[INFO] > mybusiness@2.0.7 webpack C:\dev\workspace-appli\mybusiness  
[INFO] > node --max_old_space_size=8096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config"   "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"  
[INFO]  
[ERROR] (node:18144) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead  
[INFO] Hash: d1f575c068c7812cf12c  
[INFO] Version: webpack 4.42.0  
[INFO] Time: 1586626ms
```

In my package.json :

```
- "webpack:build:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=minimal",   
- "webpack:build": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main",  
- "webpack:prod:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",  
- "webpack:prod": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www",  
- "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=8096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
```

I had to pass the parameter (max_old_space_size) to 8GB because I had an outmemory with 4GB

My version :

```
Jhipster :  
-   "generator-jhipster": "5.7.0"  
npm version :   
-   npm: '6.14.2',  
      ares: '1.14.0',  
      cldr: '33.1',
      http_parser: '2.8.0',
      icu: '62.1',
      modules: '64',
      napi: '3',
      nghttp2: '1.33.0',
      node: '10.11.0',
      openssl: '1.1.0i',
      tz: '2018e',
      unicode: '11.0',
      uv: '1.23.0',
      v8: '6.8.275.32-node.28',
      zlib: '1.2.11'  
mvnw --version  
-   Found "C:\dev\workspace-appli\mybusiness\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.jar"  
-   Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)  
node --version  
-   v10.11.0
```

Do you know how to optimize the compilation? 1 hour to compile seems abnormally long.

Comment: Can you show what's in your package.json and webpack config files?

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade JHipster to 6.8.0 to benefit from Angular 9?

Comment: my config files :   
package.json : https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aprk90GB3miwgjSuL6pgXOOpMQgV?e=NKXx0T
Webpack : https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aprk90GB3miwgji3HAWz8fvgVKI8?e=QHZlNp

Comment: I haven't tried yet to upgrade my jhipster. I plan to do it by the end of April.

Comment: Do you have a JDL file with all your entities? 47 seems like a lot so it's likely you're creating a whole bunch of TypeScript that needs to be compiled.

Comment: Has your prod build always taken long time to complete or is it it only recent?